# How to resolve "cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc." error in Oracle Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a events page in my Oracle Apex application that displays a report from "event" table and it works just fine. But when I try to edit one of those rows I get an error saying "cannot select ROWID from, or simple, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc"

[image]

Same error occurs when I try to create new event.

The data source for the event is a view with the following schema

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_EVENT" ("EVENT_ID", "EVENT_NAME", "START_DATE", "END_DATE", "START_TIME", "END_TIME", "DESCRIPTION", "FROM_COLLEGE", "FROM_COMMUNITY", "CLUB_NAME") AS 
  SELECT event."EVENT_ID"
  ,event."EVENT_NAME"
  ,event."START_DATE"
  ,event."END_DATE"
  ,event."START_TIME"
  ,event."END_TIME"
  ,event."DESCRIPTION"
  ,CASE WHEN event."FROM_COLLEGE" = 0 THEN 'No'
  WHEN event."FROM_COLLEGE" = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  END AS "From College"
  ,CASE WHEN event."FROM_COMMUNITY" = 0 THEN 'No'
  WHEN event."FROM_COMMUNITY" = 1 THEN 'Yes'
  END AS "From Community"
  ,LISTAGG(club_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY club_name) AS clubs
FROM event
LEFT JOIN (club_event INNER JOIN club ON club_event.club_id = club.club_id)
ON event.event_id = club_event.event_id
GROUP BY event."EVENT_ID"
     ,event."EVENT_NAME"
     ,event."START_DATE"
     ,event."END_DATE"
     ,event."START_TIME"
     ,event."END_TIME"
     ,event."DESCRIPTION"
     ,event."FROM_COLLEGE"
     ,event."FROM_COMMUNITY"
/
```

In summary the above code inner joins "club" with "club_event" table and then it left joins the "event" table with the result.

The error above states that the error is due to GROUP BY clause with I require since I am using the "LISTAGG" function to aggregate multiple rows of "club_name" into one comma separated row.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your query does not have an `ORDER BY` clause, and I'm not sure that using `ROWID` even makes sense.

Comment: Do you really need this level of complexity ? Create a form on table "event" and add a page item for "clubs" with that listagg query as source. Handle "clubs" in a separate page process. It looks like you are making your solution very complex for no reason...

Comment: Is it a normal form page or IG? Which column have you specified as Primary Key? If PK is ROWID, can you change it to EVENT_ID and try again?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot edit rows through the view you have created, either through APEX or directly from a SQL prompt. Because of the join and aggregation (the GROUP BY), it is not possible to identify a single row in the source tables to which an update could be applied. APEX generally requires a separate form for each table. You would need to refactor your display as a master/detail page with separate queries for each table, or to base your form on a PL/SQL package instead of a table or view.

- [APEX ORACLE How to use one form to insert data into multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883516/apex-oracle-how-to-use-one-form-to-insert-data-into-multiple-tables)
- [How can I create a insert/update form for multiple table in Oracle Apex 5.1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898670/how-can-i-create-a-insert-update-form-for-multiple-table-in-oracle-apex-5-1-4)

Comment: because I cannot edit rows through the view, I have already written a trigger function which instead of updating the view updates the real event table. For now I just want the update/create page to display properly with the data from view table so that when a user hits update/create button the trigger gets invoked. I want the primary key from the 'event' table to be used to identify rows in the view.

Comment: Samman, please watch this video to get a better understanding of what's going on: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UUMwfaXKFsg